# What does it mean when AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() returns -1?

Tags: api, macos, return-value

I have an uninstaller that calls [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges) to run some tools that perform cleanup.  On OS X 10.6 everything is fine.  On 10.5 I'm getting -1 as the return value.  The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000826-CH4g-CJBEABHG) doesn't cover what this means.

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1, as far as I can tell, just means fail.  Turns out my call to AuthorizationCreate() was failing in interesting ways, so AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() was actually behaving sort of reasonable.

Still, Apple: document your APIs better. KTHX.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what -1 means, but check if TMPDIR exists in environment and if it points to existing directory. If directory doesn't exist, unset TMPDIR. I don't remember what exactly it will return in this case, but this was very annoying bug to find...

Maybe they finally fixed it in 10.6.

Comment: During your call? I know apple installer likes playing with that variable. Maybe something else does too.